# How can you use cookies with superagent?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, superagent

I'm doing cookie session management with express with something like this:

```
req.session.authentication = auth;
```

And I verify the authenticated urls with something like

```
if(!req.session.authentication){res.send(401);}
```

Now I'm building tests for the URLs with mocha, [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.com/superagent/) and [should](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js), however I can't seem to find a way to get/set the cookie with superagent. I even tried to request the login before the authenticated test but it is not working,

I have tried adding the request to the login in the before statement for the mocha BDD suite, however it is still telling me that the request is unauthorized, I have tested the authentication doing the requests from the browser, however it is not working from the suite any ideas why?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `superagent.agent()` (instead of plain old `superagent`) to make requests have persistent cookies. See ['Saving cookies' in the superagent docs](https://ladjs.github.io/superagent/#agents-for-global-state), or the code examples: [agency.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/test/node/agency.js), [controller.test.js](https://github.com/hunterloftis/component-test/blob/master/lib/users/test/controller.test.js).

Comment: Note that `superagent.agent()` has [serious, undocumented issues in how it handles cookies](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/352) for most request definitions - anything more complicated than a `get(url,opts,cb)` requires hooking into undocumented private methods.

Comment: In fact the documentation has no mention of cookies either. I was really starting to like this library and had high hopes because of the author, but it turns out to be useless if you want to use a session cookie.

Comment: this did not work / if it did it isn't really sufficient... can someone provide an example of how that works....

Answer (score 22):

Seems like following code works fine;

> req.set('Cookie', "cookieName1=cookieValue1;cookieName2=cookieValue2");

Comment: This did not work for me using Django `{"Cookie": "csrftoken=token here"}`

Answer (score 10):

If the issue is in sending cookies for CORS requests use `.withCredentials()` method
[described here](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#cors)

```
request
  .get('http://localhost:4001/')
  .withCredentials()
  .end(function(err, res) { })
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you mentioned you need to both get *and* set the cookie:

Get:

```
const request = await Superagent.get('...')

const cookie = request.header['set-cookie']
```

Set:

```
Superagent.post('...').set('Cookie', 'cookie_info')
```

Answer (score 3):

### 2020 +

A clean way to do it is:

- create a simple cookie store
- abstract set Cookie to send it in each request
- update the cookie only when needed

*Note I keep the same URL because I use graphql but you can make it a parameter:*

```
const graph = agent =>
  agent.post('/graph')
    .set('cookie', cookieStore.get());

const handleCookie = res =>
  cookieStore.set(res.headers['set-cookie'][0]);

let currentCookie="";
const cookieStore = {
  set: cookie=>{currentCookie=cookie},
  get: cookie=>currentCookie,
};

module.exports = {graph,connectTestUser,handleCookieResponse};
```

You can now just use **graph(agent)** to send a request and **handleCookie(response)** when you have a response that may update your cookie (set or clear), example:

```
graph(agent).end((err,res) => {
  if (err) return done(err);
  res.statusCode.should.equal(200);
  handleCookie(res);
  return done();
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `res.header['set-cookie']` rather than `res.headers['set-cookie']`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a cookie to agent cookiejar:

```
const request = require('superagent');
const {Cookie} = require('cookiejar')
const agent = request.agent()

agent.jar.setCookie(new Cookie("foo=bar"))
```